# Recursively check txt file contents against a list of strings

Tags: python, string

I need to sift through a shared directory/subdirs, read through the txt files, and check whether or not certain key phrases are present in any of them.

---

```
import os

stringcheck = ['my espresso machine', 'sick of these dolphins', 
               'unpaid intern', 'dynamite']

parent = os.path.expanduser("~/Google Drive/life/aquatic")

def simplecheck(parent):
    for dir in os.walk(parent):
        for files in dir:
            if files.endswith(".txt"):
                if any(x not in files.read() for x in stringcheck):
                    print " "*4 + files + "\n"

simplecheck(parent)
```

---

This returns:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: `files` is a list, so doesn't have an `endswith` attribute (which is a string method) - what exactly is confusing you?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see, I mean for 'files' to represent individual files in the directories. The script should sift through a directory and read any .txt files it happens upon. It seems like I'm approaching this entirely the wrong way.

Comment: `list(os.walk(some_dir))` returns a list of tuples. inside of one of these tuples, is a string, a list, and a list of strings. im not seeing any actual file objects. So even if you do sort out, the `endswith('txt')` line, you are still going to have to convert that string into a file object so `.read()` method will work on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) yields tuples:

> [...]For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`.

So, you probably wanted to write:

```
for files in dir[-1]:
```

Also, `filename` would be a better name for this variable.

Comment: +1 `dir()` is a python builtin, and everyone who uses python should use `dir()` millions of times over and over, especially when starting out. Its one of the most useful builtins. I <3 `dir()`.